# stuck with root test for series convergence to $1$ for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I've got this series and I used the series convergence root test.
However my problem is: The result of the root test is one, so I can't show wheter the series converges/diverges

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$$
My approach 
$$ \sqrt[n]{\left|\left(\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|^n}
= \left|\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=1 $$

So, now I have 1 as result and can't decide wheter it converges or not?
Is there any other test I can use to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ has norm $1$, hence every power of it has norm $1$.

So the sequence

$$a_n=\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$$

is not a zero sequence, hence the series can not converge.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by norm?
Edit: So you mean the $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} =1$   
And therefore I have $1^n$?

Comment: Just the usual norm for complex numbers. If $z=a+bi$, then $|z|^2=a^2+b^2$

Comment: Yes, exactly. ;)

Comment: That is what I thought, so I first check for absolute convergence and see that it is always 1 and therefore it can't converge.
Right?

Comment: No, I was not checking if we have absolute convergence. Take a look at this very important fact: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** try computing $\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)^8$ and think of the [Term Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ has norm $1$, hence every power of it has norm $1$.

So the sequence

$$a_n=\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$$

does not tend to $0$, hence the series can not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a geometric series with ratio $\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}$ and the general term is periodic, hence it cannot converge.